# how to get the date and time html and php

Tags: php, html

I am working on a school management system. I am facing a problem while writing backend code for datesheet. I want to perform an action like admin will be able to create datesheet for student a datesheet form is given below:

```
    <br />
<br />
<br />
<form method="post" action="adddatesheet.php" >
<table>
<th colspan="4"><h1>CREATE DATESHEET</h1></th>
<?php require_once '../lib/config/Database.php';

        $DbCon = new Database();
        $DbCon->connect();
        $Class = $DbCon->select("class");

 ?>
<tr><td>Session:</td><td><input type="text" name="session" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Class :</td><td>
                    <select name="class_id">
                        <?php while($class = $Class->fetch_array()){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $class[0]; ?>"><?php echo $class[1]; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

                </td></tr>
                <?php for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){ 
                    $Subject = $DbCon->select("subject");
                ?>

                <tr>
<td>Subject :</td><td>
                    <select name="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <?php while($subject = $Subject->fetch_array()){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $subject[0]; ?>"><?php echo $subject[1]; 1?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
<td>Date :</td><td><input type="date" name="date<?php echo $i; ?>" /></td>
<td>Time :</td><td><input type="time" name="time<?php echo $i; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <?php } ?>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit-datesheet" value="Save" /></td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

i want to get the selected date and time with subjects. but i am unable to do. Here is a code to check the data

```
    <?php 

        if(isset($_POST['submit-datesheet'])){

    for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
        echo $_POST['session']."<br />";
        echo $_POST[$i]."<br />";
        echo $_POST['class_id']."<br />";
        echo $_POST['date']."<br />";
        echo $_POST['time']."<br />";

    }
        }else{
            header("LOCATION: index.php");
        }



?>
```

it doesn't return the selected date and time.

Comment: What's in this file: `../lib/config/Database.php` ?

Comment: this is my database class

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `name` of your `date` and `time` fields is dynamic (`name="date<?php echo $i; ?>"`), but your retrieval doesn't take this into account.

You should be using

```
for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
        echo $_POST['date'.$i]."<br />";
        echo $_POST['time'.$i]."<br />";

}
```

instead.